# HowTo: Query schema objects using NHibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate

How can I (using NHibernate) get all the entities that are joinable with certain entity?

For example:

Assume that we have the following tables as illustrated in the picture below:
[image]

The joinable tables for Customer would be Contact and CustomerType.

Assume that I'm using NHibernate and mapping each table of those to an entity in my model with the same name as the table, now, Is there is a way to get all the joinable tables for the Customer table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the previous post and on some other research, the answer is quite simply, you can't!

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate works based on the domain model, not the database model.

What you are showing there are database tables, so there's nothing to do with them using NHibernate.